# error when installing memcache

Tags: php, pear

i am using this command to install memcache (it do not work for other extensions)

```
C:\php>pecl install memcache
```

and it is the result :

```
downloading memcache-2.2.7.tgz ...
Starting to download memcache-2.2.7.tgz (36,459 bytes)
..........done: 36,459 bytes
11 source files, building
WARNING: php_bin C:\php\php.exe appears to have a suffix .exe, but config variable p
fix does not match
ERROR: The DSP memcache.dsp does not exist.
```

i always get this error

```
ERROR: The DSP memcache.dsp does not exist.
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to compile it from source on windows but get a pre-compiled `.dll` file from http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache

You'd need a whole development environment with visual studio to be able to compile the extension from sources. That's probably not what you want.